# Putty on linux without having to use terminal program

Tags: linux, networking, putty

Can I install Putty on Linux without having to use the terminal program? are there any ways to do that? Please if there r any websites where I can dirrectly download and install please suggest them for me

Comment: Questions asking for software are off-topic at SO. I suspect that a Google search would turn up some possibilities ("Linux Putty GUI" seems like a good thing to search). If you can't find anything that way, then http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask this

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, putty is distributed in source code form, that must be built on your specific Linux distribution.

However, there's very little need for putty on Linux in the first place. Most Linux distributions already include other applications that do everything putty does.

Putty is just an ssh client. All modern Linux distributions include ssh as part of their base distribution.

Comment: No, putty is an ssh client **and a terminal emulator** - but I've yet to come across a Linux distribution which doesn't include both by default.